# How can I use a Citizen CY dye sublimation printer with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a *Citizen CY* dye sublimation printer, which has both Windows drivers and Mac drivers but no Linux drivers. I've looked at converting the Windows drivers, and have a vague understanding of the complications. However, with Apple being a UNIX based operating system, I was thinking it might be slightly more straightforward to get started on converting the Mac driver instead?

Answer (score 2):

Install `Gutenprint`. It supports your printer. Install these files from the Ubuntu repos...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgutenprint2 printer-driver-gutenprint
reboot
```

then try and add your printer via System Settings.

If that didn't work for you, you'll have to download the source code and compile it yourself.

Performing a Google search for `Gutenprint` will provide more information, and download locations for the source code.